# Insert JSON Array into Elasticsearch Using Python Bulk API

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I have a JSON array of 100 records , I want to insert it into elasticsearch ,I tried it using the below code but it gives me JSON Error exception . I am not sure where I am doing it wrong . The code which I am using to insert record is

```
from esService.esClient import ESCient
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

#data is the json array object which has around 100 records in it .

#I want to insert it into elasticsearch in such a way 

#that each record is a entry into ES (I can remove the ID if required  ,I don't need the ID ) 

    def insert_bulk_record(self,index,data,id):
        docs = []
        doc = {
            "_index": index,
            "_id": id,
            "_source": data
        }
        docs.append(doc)

        bulk(self.esconnect, docs)
```

When I do bulk insert using the above code I get the below exception ,

```
elasticsearch.helpers.errors.BulkIndexError: ('1 document(s) failed to index.', [{'index': {'_index': 'data_record', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '7908745568_0.csv', 'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'reason': 'failed to parse', 'caused_by': {'type': 'not_x_content_exception', 'reason': 'Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are not passing the correct format to Elastic for indexing the data.
`Bulk helpers` accept single JSON objects and not JSON arrays.

For example, you might try something like this:

```
for d in data:
    docs = []
    doc = {
        "_index": index,
        "_source": d
    }
    docs.append(doc)

    bulk(self.esconnect, docs)
```

Have a look at this [blog](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-use-python-helpers-to-bulk-load-data-into-an-elasticsearch-index) as well.